# Force full screen for mobile websites?

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, mobile-application, fullscreen

Is it ok to force full screen for mobile websites to make them seem more like native mobile apps?

- jQuery: http://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/
- iOS 7.1 `minimal-ui`: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7424814

Thinking that this in combination with [How usable are bars that disappear / reappear on scroll?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57990/how-usable-are-bars-that-disappear-reappear-on-scroll) could really help free up real-estate. Should probably provide some sort of "easy exit arrow" at the top right corner though.

On the downside, doing this without the user's permission might be a no-no. Likewise, asking the user for permission via some popup might be too spammy.

What y'all think?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it may depend on **the role of the app** (e.g. how important it is to the user),
**its users** (e.g. how likely are they to click outside the app by mistake)
and it definitely depends on whether the user has given **permission** to the site to act like this or not.