# Mobile ui design - Scrolling effect to hide navbar and show it on scroll up

Tags: gui-design, animation

I am looking for examples of the effect used mostly in mobile design, where by scrolling down the navbar hides from view, and by scrolling up again it returns in view.

Does this effect have a specific name?

Comment: "Annoying".  You scroll down, realize you've gone a bit too far, scroll back up -- and have the thing you were trying to see go from "almost visible" to "solidly hidden".

Answer (score 6):

This types of NavBars are known as **Pit bars** according to [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57990/how-usable-are-bars-that-disappear-reappear-on-scroll) answer.

Comment: That's an interesting name. I would have never guessed :D

Answer (score 1):

**I found 2 good examples:**

1. [Show & Hide Navbar on Scroll - Webflow interactions and animations
   tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2Kp4bSDCwI)
2. [How to Hide a Navigation Bar When Scrolling Down - HTML, CSS &
   JavaScript Web Design Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_XZk5Vnujw)

But as far as know, this navbar doesn't have any specific name. I would call it the "**Interactive navbar**" because it describes the main mechanics — interactivity.

Comment: Would you happen to have some examples from Design System resources?